# get value of hidden field inside for each loop in jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

I have a jsp which displays a single question with multiple choice answers, like a survey. Only a single question is displayed at a time. This is the code.

```
<c:forEach items="${questions}" var="question" varStatus="loop1">
    <div id="offer-quiz-${loop1.index}" class="offer-quiz-main">Give us your valuable opinion!

    <%
       count++;
       pageContext.setAttribute("count", count);
    %>

  <div id="offer-quiz-hd" div class="offer-quiz-hdr">Question ${count}: </div>
    <div class="offer-quiz-ques">${question.values}</div>
        <div class="offer-quiz-ans">

          <c:forEach items="${question.answers}" var="answer" varStatus="loop2">
           <span><input name="qa${loop1.index}" id="radio_${loop1.index}${loop2.index}" type="radio" value="${answer.answers}">
            <label for="radio_${loop1.index} ${loop2.index}">${answer.answers}</label>
           </span>

            <div><input id="nextQId-${loop1.index}${loop2.index}" type="hidden" value="${answer.nextqid}"></div>
          </c:forEach>
          <div class="offer-quiz-btns">
            <a href="#" class="quiz-btn-g">Go Back</a>
            <a href="#" class="quiz-btn">Next</a>
          </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</c:forEach>
```

I pass the questions and answers from a database and pass it to the jsp as a list. I loop through the questions and use a second loop for the answers. I have a hidden div inside the second loop:

So for each answer the value of this field would be different. I would like to get the value of this field when a button is clicked, in javascript.

Can someone please help me?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have the same index in your hidden and radio button, you can use it to get the value of your hidden using simple javascript.

```
<script>
    function getHiddenValue(answer){
     var index = answer.id.indexOf("_");
     var id = answer.id.substring(index+1);
     alert(document.getElementById("nextQId-"+id).value);  
    }
</script>
```

**Radio Button**

```
<input name="qa${loop1.index}" id="radio_${loop1.index}${loop2.index}" type="radio" value="${answer.answers}" onclick="getHiddenValue(this);">
```

Here's a [JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qhx8ojtu/) example.

Comment: Hi tks for the input. I wanted to get the value of the hidden field when you click on a button after selecting a particular radio button.

Comment: Hi Tks its working now! I was just wondering, how do I increment the Question no each time the page is loaded? Right now I use this: 

<%
                               count++;
                               pageContext.setAttribute("count", count);
                            %>

But if I skip a question then it increases by 2. So if a user select s option 1 from the first question it should display the 3rd question. Then the count also increases by 2. But I need to increment it by 1 only.

Comment: I see two options here, 1. Do not allow users to skip a question this will be easy. 2. allow skip then check if user select a radio button, if user checked a button increment count, if not do nothing. You can do it with javascript.

Comment: If this help, you can click the check button to accept the answer or also you can up vote or down vote an answer. I notice you didn't accept any answer to your questions.

Comment: Tks for the help. It was very useful:)